# Unexpected 0 appear in bubble sort function

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I am new to C language and I am currently learning to write a basic function of bubble sort. Everything seems good and the rest of the program runs well. However, there is an unexpected 0 appears in the output. I checked my code and I didn't know why. Could somebody help me?
A Sample of input and output:

```
The orginal number set is:   23   12   17    8    5   46   75   19   11    4
The sorted number set is:  0  4  5  8 11 12 17 19 23 46
```

The code is :

```
// wirte a program of bubble sort

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num[10];    // a set to store10 numbers
    int temp;   //a temporary variable
    int i,r,t,p,d;  //counters
    //store 10 numbers 
    for(i=0; i<10;++i)
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter the %dth number.\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&num[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //display 10 numbers
    printf("The orginal number set is:");
    for(r=0; r<10; ++r)
    {
        printf("%5d",num[r]);    
    }
    printf("\n");
    //start to sort these numbers
    for (p=0;p<10;++p)    
    {
        for(t=0;t<10;++t)
        {
            if(num[t]>num[t+1])
            {
                temp=num[t];
                num[t]=num[t+1];
                num[t+1]=temp;
            } 
        } 
    }
    //print out the sorted set
    printf("The sorted number set is:");
    for(d=0;d<10;++d)
    {
        printf("%3d",num[d]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: 1. That isn't bubble sort. 2. `num[t+1]` dereferences `num[10]` when `t == 9`, which it will as the last round of the inner loop, and is out of range, therefore invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much. 1. I solved the mistake by changing `t<10` to `t<9`  2. Why this is not a bubble sort? Isn't bubble sort to compare the number with the next number, and compare again until it gets the largest number in a round?

Comment: Bubblesort has *swap-detection*. It detects a sorted sequence and aborts the sort upon detecting said-same. If any pass fails to produce a swap, the sequence is, by definition, sorted and the algorithm is done. It is what gives bubblesort a best-case complexity of O(n) (one of the few sorting algorithms that has that feature). A sorted sequence of N items sent to bubblesort will  have exactly (N-1) comparisons, then terminate. [see example](http://pastebin.com/3jXgNZkx)

Comment: ...but don't be discouraged. You did get the adjacent-element comparison part of the algorithm correct, which is the place most people drop the ball, so you were mostly there. Just indexing limits and swap detection are off. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you, I will dig into that and refine the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are comparing the values. You also compare the last one, with the first one outside the array. This happens to be 0(undefined behaviour,totally dependent on compiler) and gets switched in. The for-loop should become:

```
for (p=0;p<10;++p)    
{
    for(t=0;t<9;++t)
    {
        if(num[t]>num[t+1])
        {
            temp=num[t];
            num[t]=num[t+1];
            num[t+1]=temp;
        } 
    } 
}
```